# Spotify cocoalibspotify offline status set to 1 but all tracks stuck at waiting

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm trying to allow tracks from Spotify to be played offline in my iOS app. I've read several posts about this problem, but none of the suggestions work for me.

The issue is a playlist marked for download gets stuck with all tracks "waiting" to be downloaded. I can recreate it regularly in a fresh app install by creating a playlist, adding a few tracks, and mark playlist for download. Tracks download as expected. Then I background the app by tapping the home button and kill the app in the app tray. Then I start the app and successfully login with – attemptLoginWithUserName:existingCredential: I create another playlist, add some more tracks and mark for offline. The new playlist's offline status shows downloaded, but all the tracks are waiting.

I've tried:

1) flushCaches: after playlists are downloaded

2) flushCaches: in applicationDidEnterBackground

3) logout in applicationDidEnterBackground:

4) logout in applicationWillTerminate:

5) setting badly behaving playlist markedforofflineplayback to off, flush caches and set markedforofflineplayback to off again.

So far, once a playlist has gotten stuck, the only way to get another playlist downloaded has been to delete the app and reinstall.

Does anyone have other suggestions for how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue that an update will fix soon. In the meantime, if a playlist gets stuck you can delete the cache folder that CocoaLibSpotify creates which is one step short of reinstalling, but not exactly a useful workaround.

Comment: Thanks iKenndac, for the quick reply! If I promise not to hold you to it, would you guess this fix in days, weeks or months? I could release my next version without Spotify functionality, or wait for the fix.

Comment: It's probably best to assume weeks-months just so you don't get annoyed with waiting :-P

Comment: I updated to libspotify 12.1.51 and it seems to be working. Is the fix already complete?

Comment: No. CococaLibSpotify stayed at .1.45 because our tests showed that .1.51 crashed a lot under heavy load on iOS. There are no specific offlining fixed between .1.45 and .1.51 - we'll be releasing a much newer build soon.

Comment: I'm not getting annoyed. I promise ;-) Just wondering if there is any news on this update and potential fix. Should I be watching for a libspotify or CocoaLibSpotify update?

Comment: CocoaLibSpotify will be updated at the same time and will automatically use the newer libspotify.

Comment: Any news on this fix? Again, I'm totally not annoyed ;-)

Comment: Just checking in to see if there is any news on the update that fixes this problem. Thanks in advance for any news.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if 'libspotify-12.1.62' for 2.4.3 fixes this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately 12.1.62 is just a hotfix for an issue that prevented people submitting apps to the App Store. Check the release notes for a list of what's new with each release.

Comment: Hi iKenndac, any word on when a fix for this issue could show up?

Comment: Yes, the update to CocoaLibSpotify that was released a couple of weeks ago fixes it. You really should check those release notes :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Sorry, but I didn't see anything in the CHANGELOG.markdown file that indicated this fix.

Comment: Sorry to bring this issue back from the dead, but I'm getting the same issue with 12.1.64.  I'm marking a playlist for offline playback, and then checking the status periodically.  After a fresh install the very first status is 3 at 0% downloaded, and from then on the status is 1 at 0%.