# CocoaLibSpotify OfflineStatus of Track added to 'markedForOfflinePlayback' Playlist after application restart always SP_TRACK_OFFLINE_WAITING

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

So I have a problem with CocoaLibSpotify a lot of developers used to have(but that 'has been fixed with updates' and I am on the newest version). There are a lot of posts about this on the web, e.g.: [Spotify cocoalibspotify offline status set to 1 but all tracks stuck at waiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658390/spotify-cocoalibspotify-offline-status-set-to-1-but-all-tracks-stuck-at-waiting). I've tried all of the fixes suggested, also things like logging out and in again, logging out with and without a background task when the app is terminated. I now had this issue for about two weeks and didn't find a solution. Anybody having an Idea of why this could happen/how to fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm also having this issue, did you ever get it working?

Comment: No, the Spotify API is pretty strange at this point: unstable and buggy. Have no idea why this is happening!

Comment: For what it's worth, I finally got it working.  Not sure I can tell you what I was doing wrong, but the unit tests [here](https://github.com/epatel/cocoalibspotify/blob/dev/common/Tests/SPPlaylistTests.m) are a good working example.

Comment: Do you remember anything that you've changed?

Comment: It's definitely something to do with the logout method.  Being logged in as a different user, logging out, then logging in as a new user caused offline playlists not to download.  Now that I stay logged in and don't mess with switching accounts, it works well.

Comment: Hmm, I don't login with different credentials... So that can't have caused it for me.